# Performance of for loops in Julia

Tags: performance, for-loop, julia

I tried the following codes but the performance is extremely different
among codes. I heard that codes at the top level are not suited for numerical computation, but the performance also seems to depend on whether
top-level variables (here, N) appear in the range of for-loops.
Is it always better to avoid such top-level variables?

```
N = 10000000

# case1 (slow)
x = 0.0
@time for k = 1:N
    x += float( k )
end

# case2 (slow)
@time let
    y = 0.0
    for j = 1:N
        y += float( j )
    end
end

# case3 (very fast)
@time let
    n::Int64
    n = N
    z = 0.0
    for m = 1:n
        z += float( m )
    end
end

# case 4 (slow)
function func1()
  c = 0.0
  for i = 1:N                                             
    c += float( i )
  end
end

# case 5 (fast)
function func2( n )                                          
  c = 0.0
  for i = 1:n
    c += float( i )
  end
end

# case 6 (fast)
function func3()
  n::Int
  n = N
  c = 0.0
  for i = 1:n                                   
    c += float( i )
  end
end

# case 7 (slow)
function func4()
  n = N        # n = int( N ) is also slow                                  
  c = 0.0
  for i = 1:n
    c += float( i )
  end
end

@time func1()
@time func2( N )
@time func3()
@time func4()
```

The result obtained with Julia 0.3.7 (on Linux x86_64) is

```
elapsed time: 2.595440598 seconds (959985496 bytes allocated, 10.70% gc time)
elapsed time: 2.469471127 seconds (959983688 bytes allocated, 11.49% gc time)
elapsed time: 1.608e-6 seconds (16 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 2.535243279 seconds (960021976 bytes allocated, 11.21% gc time)
elapsed time: 0.002601149 seconds (75592 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.003471583 seconds (84456 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 2.480343146 seconds (960020752 bytes allocated, 11.48% gc time)
```

Comment: Avoiding global variables is the first tip in the [Julia performance tips](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/performance-tips/). You may be getting {constant folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) in the third (super-fast) case. (the `code_native` and `code_lllvm` functions are useful to check).

Comment: @Isaiah Thanks for your advice. Although for large programs I usually avoid such global variables, I wanted to use them for very short codes. Following  [Julia perfomance tips](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/) I also tested to replace N by N::Int (except for the declaration at the top level), which also made all the Cases as fast as attaching 'const'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer taking "Is it always better to avoid such top-level variables?" literal is of course "No, it depends", but a useful remark is that declaring global variables as constant

```
const N = 10000000
```

makes case 2 as fast as case 3.

Edit: I should add that the problem for case 2 is that the top level `N` makes the type of the range `1:N` and iterator variable `j` unstable, even if the accumulator variable `y` is local. A more flexible fix for this problem is

```
   let
       y = 0.0
       for j = 1:(N::Int)
           y += float( j )
       end
       y
   end
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Indeed, attaching 'const' to the global variable N has made other codes also faster (e.g., Case 1 now takes only 0.4 sec, Cases 4 and 7 are as fast as Cases 5 and 6).